# How do I transparently enable ccache for multiple toolchains?

Tags: linux, cross-compilation

I want to turn on ccache both for primary compiler like `gcc` or `clang` and also for toolchains in android-ndk and other cross-compilers.

How do I do it in one move, without explicitly iterating over toolchains and without modifications requiring merging when toolchains get updated? Maybe there is some, for example LD_PRELOAD-based solution?